# AngularJS ng-option get index

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options

I'm making a playlist option in the project I'm working on and I'm trying to get a dropdown for all the videos in the list.

which is easy

```
<select ng-options="vid.Id for vid in playList.Videos track by video.Id" ng-model="selected" class="browser-default"></select>
```

but this shows a drop down of the Id's, but now I want it to show the position in the list +1;

So when playing video 5/15 the drop down should show 1 to 15 (so not 0 to 14) and 5 should be selected.

any idea on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to display index of the current video as option text, then this ngOptions expression should do the trick:

```
ng-options="vid as playList.Videos.indexOf(vid)+1 for vid in playList.Videos track by video.Id"
```

The key here is that you can use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) method on `Videos` array to calculate current video index, and then add `1`.

Comment: you wouldn't by chance know how to preselect the right video? if I add the ng-model with the right video object, it always selects the last one (although the ng-model  has the same object as one of the list)

Comment: How do you set model? Can you share some code maybe here: http://plnkr.co/edit/0RNYkctZCu9n4PpekFVf?p=preview

Comment: Hmm, apparently i did something wrong somewhere, the code in the plnkr fixed my issue :)

Answer (score -2):

You can track by the index of the array. 
$index is set to the item index or key.

```
<select ng-options="vid as ($index + 1) for vid in playList.Videos track by $index" ng-model="selected" class="browser-default"></select>
```

Comment: Helpfull, but the other is preciser, but slower (although there both fast)

Comment: `ngOptions` doesn't support `$index`, this is not the same as `ngRepeat`.